# Swift - Getting Contact Details from ContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I have an application that has some fields for a person's name, email, and address. I have utilized the [CNContactPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactViewController_Class/) and have the delegate stated in my application header. On a button click, I have the following:

```
@IBAction func AddItemFromContactsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
        [CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
    self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

afterwards, when the user selects a contact, I have the delegate method [didSelectContact](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CNContactPickerDelegate/contactPicker:didSelectContact:) and have utilized it as follows:

```
//DELEGATE METHODS FOR UICONTACT
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact){
    ItemName.text = contact.givenName + " " + contact.familyName
    if(contact.phoneNumbers.count != 0){
        ItemPhoneContact.text = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value as? String
    }
    if(contact.postalAddresses.count != 0){
        ItemAddress.text = contact.postalAddresses[0].value as? String
    }
}
```

However I get a runtime error on pulling the postalAddresses. When commneted out, I get the following warning on runtime for getting the phone numbers:

```
[Appname ####:####] plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactsViewService invalidated
```

Any ideas as to what is going on? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I would just like to note that getting the name and family name works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you request permission for contacts via `CNContactStore.requestAccessForEntityType`? What is `CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType` returning? You can show ContactsUI, but when you go to retrieve information, you need to make sure that the user granted authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this message because in IOS 9 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is no longer works.

There is new library/framework for CNContact which will be used in IOS 9 and above: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html

Comment: So this is with the ContactStore, is there any way to still display the picker/controller for the /user/ to pick the contact? (and then from that get the number and address, if any)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CNContactViewController  to show contact details based on name.

```
let name = "\(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName)"
let predicate: NSPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: name)
let descriptor = CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()
let contacts: [CNContact]
do {
  contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: [descriptor])
  } catch {
    contacts = []
  }

if !contacts.isEmpty {
  guard let contact.first else {return}
  let cvc = CNContactViewController(for: contact)
    cvc.allowsActions = true
    cvc.delegate = self
    cvc.allowsEditing = true
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cvc, animated: true)
  }
```